# Failed audit in Low Quality Answer Queue, why?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, specific-audit

I was reviewing the Low Quality Answers queue on SO, and stumbled upon an audit which, in my opinion, is totally wrong.
Here is the audit in question: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/34875686

The reviewed answer was deleted as **spam/offensive** 4 days ago, even though it is a collection of links to documentation which are relevant to the question.

The question is very old and closed as it did not fit SO. The answer is very recent yet relevant, and I don't see any reason why it was deleted as offensive.

If it had been deleted as Low Quality because of the answer almost being links only (though relevant and in a closed question anyway), I might have just skipped over that failed audit and forgot about it, but in this situation I think the audit should be removed.

PS: *This is probably going to be marked as duplicate, since there are a lot of "audit failed" question on here, but the goal is to dispute that audit and get it removed, as it has been done in multiple other similar instances.*

Comment: It's not only spammy, it's blatantly spammy.

Comment: @yivi please explain why?

Comment: Any screenshot for non-10k?

Comment: The sole purpose of the post is to promote a code-checker product.

Comment: @yivi not sure it's that blatant. I saw it and wouldn't have flagged it by itself. But [this other post](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/435025) did convince me that the post linked here was also spam.

Comment: @AndrewT. [Smokey report](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/435026)

Comment: VLAZ, that post you mentioned indeed convinces me that it's spam/promotion too, but definitely not blatant to me, interested to know how @yivi find it blatant?

Comment: Normally I would click skip, but in this case the post is nothing but links, and that's the kiss of death. I might not have gotten "Spam" out of it, I'm too paranoid to click links to unrecognized sites, but it's definitely not OK.

Comment: It was a collection of multiple links to a "Code Checker for MatLAB", a collection of links, does not answer the question that was asked.  **I would agree the only reason those links existed were to promote a product**

Comment: Yeah, the same people always say "it's obviously SPAM" when it's anything of the sort. It's not a good answer because it's almost 100% links, and it should at least smell a little spammy to you, but there's no way for you to know whether the user stumbled upon what they thought were useful links or whether they really are just another spammer.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk the thing is, we *don't actually care*. From our perspective, a well-meaning person dropping by to promote something they liked is not really doing anything different from a paid shill. https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion is relevant here also.

Comment: @VLAZ, Thanks for the "Smokey Report"/Screenshot (I'm also a <10k User (<1k even!)), => Qt downvoted for OP not adding that info. // And the Post/Audit is also super obvious Spam to me... (I (only) checked the 1st Link.)

Comment: There is that conflict of terminology again, IMO. "spam" is a widely known thing due to its usage in the area of email. Many websites consider posts to be spam when they are created in the same way as spam email, I.E. just blasting gibberish on a large scale. I think most people would call that "blatant spam", where it just can't be interpreted any other way. But on Stack Overflow there is a whole other layer to it, including individuals which ignorantly or cunningly put advertisement links in their posts. That will only be obvious to people who know what to look for.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> The reviewed answer was deleted as spam/offensive 4 days ago, even though it is a collection of links to documentation which are relevant to the question.

No. It is a collection of links to some third party's coding standards. **Those aren't documentation**. Even if MATLAB offered "official" coding standards (not at all the norm for programming languages, but [Python](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) does for example), to be counted as "documentation" they would have to be:

- **written by authors or maintainers** of (or contributors to) MATLAB; and
- hosted **on a domain controlled** by such people (such as an official development repository, a site like [Read the Docs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read_the_Docs) that is sourced from such a repository, or a website explicitly created by the language authors to promote the language).

The links exist to promote the content on that third-party site. After the bulleted list, there is another link to a tool offered by that third-party. That's **clearly promotional, and thus spam**.

Here are some other checks you should do in the LQA queue:

- Check the domains on links. Do you see multiple links to the same domain in a small space? That should automatically raise suspicion.
- Look at the user's profile. This user had no other questions or answers - since this answer was deleted, the user now shows as "hasn't posted yet". First off, that tells you that the answer was deleted, which implies it was definitely not "OK". Second, the account *has existed for more than 8 years, but* has no other visible questions or answers. That should automatically raise suspicion.
- Look at the question. It was closed a few hours after the answer was posted (and, in fact, minutes *before* the answer was deleted). The question is also 12 years old (which you can see without opening the question); new answers on ancient questions (and you acknowledge you already noticed this!) should automatically raise suspicion.

  - Examining the question shows that it clearly should be closed by contemporary standards - in fact, even the title makes the problem clear: we don't want "best practices" questions here, because they [are too subjective](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and often (as in this case) seek third-party resources. New answers that are attempting to answer subjective questions like that should automatically raise suspicion.
- What does the answer look like if the links are removed? Now all you have, in effect, is "there exists a tool that can be used to check your code against a coding standard". Remember that we don't allow link-only answers; answers **need to be able to stand on their own if the links fail**. Does this claim, that such a tool exists, answer the question as asked? Clearly not. Therefore, even if not spam, it does not meet answer criteria.

Answer (score 19):

This was, indeed, a failure on your part. The post in question is spam. MATLAB documentation doesn't live at the URLs that were in the post. Even if they did, [we don't allow link-only posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370). The only exception (requests for official docs URLs) doesn't apply here, because the question itself is not asking for official docs.

Comment: While I now understand why is it spam, another answer on that question was as "link-only" as this one, and the question was actually very prone to sending links to relevant docs, since it was requesting best practices.
Also my point was indeed that I would have better understood my error if it was for being link-only than being reported as spam/offensive since it's quite subtle

Comment: Requesting best practices? Risky thing to do around here. Most of the time that's a sign that the question is also destined for the garbage bin.

Comment: @user4581301 As I mentioned, the question was indeed already deleted...

Comment: @Gugu72 the answer was deleted. The question doing the asking yet lives.

Comment: @user4581301 No, the question is closed

Comment: @Gugu72 which is different from deleted. Though it's pretty close to being deleted.

Comment: @Gugu72 - The other answer in that case is low quality. Does not change the fact the answer you reviewed was spam. Don’t defend your incorrect review by pointing out low quality content wasn’t handled properly since that will only result in that low quality contribution being handled properly. **The answer in question, the subject of this question, was spam.**

Comment: @user4581301 - Question was also deleted recently.